# Create a VBA Outlook 2010 script upon send to prompt for an answer

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I would like to create a VBA script in Outlook 2010 that upon a user pressing the send button a dialogue box appears and asks them a question where the answer is either 'Yes or No'. If they answer Yes the email is sent as normal but if the answer No then the email is not send and they are taken back to the email to make any changes.

I have a script at the moment which I was working with (borrowed :)), see below but it only gives me an OK button and even if I hit the red cross it still sends the email - any help will be very much appreciated

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
EmailSend = MsgBox("Is Your Recipient Correct?")
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In the "ThisOutlookSession" module, you can use something like this:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    If MsgBox("Yes or no?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Cancel = True
End Sub
```

It prompts with a "Yes/No" message box (because of the vbYesNo argument) and then you provide a True boolean value to "Cancel" based on the response to the dialog.  Also, at least on Windows 7, the red "x" is disabled when using the yes/no prompt.  But if not, then I would do something like this:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    Cancel = True
    If MsgBox("Yes or no?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Cancel = True Else Cancel = False
End Sub
```

Thus, it always cancels unless they say "Yes" specifically.